# Developing software on linux

Tags: linux, c++, programming, ide, c#

What tools or IDEs do I need to start developing software on Linux in C++?

Can I work using C#?

What are necessary skills in order to know to develop software on Linux? I mean what is required in the firms mostly to work as Software engineer on Linux?

Comment: If you're going to develop software on linux, I believe you should learn to like C and ASM :-)

Comment: The answer really depends on your definition of "firms" and "work as software engineer". Depending upon the job given to you, you might need to learn everything or nothing. If you are asked to develop Android Apps (for e.g.) on Linux, I doubt you would need much knowledge of Linux per se. However, if they ask you to participate in the development of a certain software, you would need to have skills enumerated below. Certain distros will enable you to do everything through GUI including SSH, Editing, Coding etc. Whether you choose VIM or GEDIT or Eclipse is your choice.

Comment: Yes I was talking about software that is tightly connected with linux (linux core stuff). Android is Java and I dont need linux knowledge to develop.

Comment: Is it payed job or its like developing opensource software for example ubuntu?

Comment: Wow C and ASM, top combination :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For developing C/C++ you need the gcc compiler, which is included in most Linux distributions or can be easily installed.

There is not a default IDE: most people use their favorite editor (vim, emacs, Geany etc...) and there are IDEs like Eclipse or KDevelop available.

C# can be done with [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page), but it is not fully compatible with .NET: check [the compatibility list](http://www.mono-project.com/Compatibility).

Comment: Or you can use llvm/clang.

Comment: Good C++ IDE for Linux == [Qt Creator](http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools/).

Comment: To add on what @GeorgeEdison said, Qt provides a very good toolkit for UI design. However, I don't know if there has bindings for C#.

Comment: will surely try Qt Creator. I worked on Eclipse before, Java but never C/C++. KDevelop also sounds good, for KDE.

Answer (score 3):

Stay with gcc compiler and Vim as an IDE. There are a lot of plugins for Vim that improves the experience in almost coding languages, but you should learn Vim first if you want to take advantage of that though.

On the other side, I think just a few "firms" are naming "C#" and "Linux" in the same context.

Comment: How can you honestly recommend Vim as an IDE in 2012?

Comment: Wait, Vim isnt that terminal editor that writes the text over the already entered text :) :P I would recomend pico/nano for terminal, they are far more better.

Comment: @Vlad they are easier to learn, but not better. Vim is powerful.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there's no ideal IDE in Linux for C++ and C# but there are many IDE based on GCC and GDB to compile and debug your codes I prefer and suggest you to work with 
[eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) and [QtCreator](http://qt.nokia.com/products). 
The NetBeans IDE also provides C++ for you but this is basically for Java programmers.